# Bad performance on search API with reducer

Tags: javascript, react-native

I built a search for my react native app. All is working as expected but I have bad performance.

Here is my searchbar component:

```
  <TextInput
    autoCapitalize='none'
    autoCorrect={false}
    style={styles.inputStyle}
    placeholder='Search'
    value={term}
    onChangeText={onTermChange}
    onEndEditing={onTermSubmit}
    returnKeyType='search'
  />
</View>
```

This is the searchscreen where I'm using the searchbar component

```
const search = term => {
    fetchData(
      `URL?term=${term}`
    );
};

<SearchBar
  term={term}
  onTermChange={setTerm}
  onTermSubmit={() => {
    search(term);
  }}
/>
```

`onTermSubmit` should run only `onEndEditing` calling `fetchData`with the term.

`fetchData` is my reducer which looks like this:

```
const dataFetchReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_INIT":
      return {
        isLoading: true
      };
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return { isLoading: false, data: action.payload.result.data };
    case "FETCH_FAILURE":
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const fetchData = dispatch => {
  return async url => {
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_INIT" });
    try {
      const result = await axios(url);
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: { result } });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_FAILURE" });
    }
  };
};
```

For the reducer I use `useContext`.

However, when I console log(state.data) I notice that I'm getting back data as soon as I type. I guess that's why I have bad performance. Not sure why, though. I thought fetchData only runs when the user tabs the search button on the keyboard?

Comment: Are you using `react-native-elements`?

Comment: No. I'm using Expo if that's relevant.

Comment: Oh my bad you have your own SearchBar component. So here are few suggestions.
1. Instead of onEndEditing you can use onBlur when you click outside the TextInput
2. Since you dont want to rerender the search bar, try using useRef for your reducer

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me with how the useRef hook would be used to not rerender the search bar? Never used useRef before.

Comment: This blog will help you jump into useRef https://medium.com/@rossbulat/react-using-refs-with-the-useref-hook-884ed25b5c29